# Closure for call back by using Generics to pass struct as parameter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics, codable

I am trying to send selected data from child view controller to parent view controller using closure as a call back mechanism. In UI having four drop downs and for that child View controller is used. Now, on each drop down a struct model class is passed to it containing their respective data. So now, when passing back selected data to the parent view need to use their respected struct classes.

For more understanding code is below what i tried so far:

```
struct Roles : Codable {
let roleId : Int?
let roleName, roleContent : String?

private enum Codingkeys: String, CodingKey
{
    case roleId = "roleId"
    case roleName = "roleName"
    case roleContent = "roleContent"

}
}
```

// ChildViewController

```
 var myRoless = [Roles]()
 var completionHandler:((String) -> Int)?

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let result = completionHandler?(myRoless[indexPath.row])

    print("completionHandler returns... \(String(describing: result))")

    removeAnimate()
}
```

// ParentViewController

```
childEditTaskViewController?.completionHandler = { text in

          //  print("text = \(text)")
            strSelectedValue = text
 }
```

Error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Roles' to expected argument type 'String
```

Above is what i tried so far

Comment: looks like you are passing a Roles, do you mean 'myRoless[indexPath.row]. roleName' ?

Comment: @WelcomeNewUsers want to return whole item at index, there is a dictionary at index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your clouser to this:

```swift
var completionHandler:((Roles) -> Void)?
```

then you can call it in this way:

```swift
childEditTaskViewController?.completionHandler = { role in

      //  print("text = \(text)")
      strSelectedValue = role.roleName // or role. roleContent
 }
```

Update:I did this way because i have to return result also

```
var completionHandlerRol : ((Roles) -> ())?
```

Comment: I think it's an incomplete answer @Mac3n. Is it "var completionHandler:((String) -> Int)?" correct

Comment: Secondly, i need to use generics here so that using same code multiple structs can be passed.

Comment: variables and expressions can't be generic. There are only generic functions and generic types.

Comment: i did this way: "var completionHandlerRol : ((Roles) -> ())?" because i want to return result as well.